# What is a right way to Increment

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, increment

I am making a 'Rock, Paper and Scissor" project for TheOdinProject, but here I am stuck on Increment phase, I tried so many actions, iterations, modified it again and again, but still got stuck on same phase.
I just want to Increment player and computer score at a given position.

```
const startGame = document.querySelector('#startGame');
const container = document.querySelector('#container');


//Start The Game
startGame.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.setAttribute('class', 'hidden');

  const buttons = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];
  const buttonContainer = document.createElement('div');
  buttonContainer.setAttribute('class', 'buttonContainer');
  const resultContainer = document.createElement('div');
  resultContainer.setAttribute('id', 'resultContainer');
  const playerScoreContainer = document.createElement('div');
  playerScoreContainer.setAttribute('id', 'playerScoreContainer');
  const computerScoreContainer = document.createElement('div');
  computerScoreContainer.setAttribute('id', 'computerScoreContainer');

  for (const button of buttons) {
    const createButton = document.createElement('button');
    createButton.textContent = button;
    createButton.setAttribute('name', `${button}`);
    buttonContainer.appendChild(createButton);
    container.appendChild(buttonContainer);


    createButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const playerSelection = e.target.getAttribute('name');
      const computerSelection = buttons[Math.floor(Math.random() * buttons.length)];
      let getPlayerPoints = 0;
      let getComputerPoints = 0;
      let gameTie = '';

      switch (true) {
        case (playerSelection === computerSelection):
          gameTie = 'Tie';
          break;
        case (
          (playerSelection === 'Rock' && computerSelection === 'Scissor') ||
          (playerSelection === 'Scissor' && computerSelection === 'Paper') ||
          (playerSelection === 'Paper' && computerSelection === 'Rock')
        ):
          playerScoreContainer.textContent = getPlayerPoints++;
          break;
        case (
          (computerSelection === 'Rock' && playerSelection === 'Scissor') ||
          (computerSelection === 'Scissor' && playerSelection === 'Paper') ||
          (computerSelection === 'Paper' && playerSelection === 'Rock')
        ):
          computerScoreContainer.textContent = getComputerPoints++;
          break;
      }

      resultContainer.append(playerScoreContainer, computerScoreContainer);
      container.appendChild(resultContainer);

    })
  }
});
```

Comment: You should forget that switch statements can be used like that. It is a bad practice.

Comment: Every time someone clicks on createButton, the player and computer points are set to 0.  You might want to put those declarations in the global scope.

Comment: I accept it, but I tries the other ways too, also tried `if` statement... but this is not working... is there any other problem?

Comment: @James thanks, Can you please explain the reason just briefly... why this set to 0

Comment: Your variable is in the listener so it will be lost, if you want to keep it between clicks it should be outside the listener

Comment: @James ok I Got it, thanks dudes

Comment: Also note that the `++` operator usedd as a suffix, changes the variable's value *after* it is used in the expression.  So if a=0, then `b = a++` sets b to 0, then increments a